# Error no 1064 in Codeigniter while entering the data with special character " or '

Tags: php, sql

I am getting and error when I enter any special character in artist_as field. Error no 1064 in CodeIgniter while entering the data with special character `"` or `'`

Here is my model code:

```
$this->db->query("Delete from tv_cast where tv_id = '{$tvid}'");
if(array_key_exists('tv_cast_as_artist_id', $post)){
    $count = count($post['tv_cast_as_artist_id']);
    $i = 0;
    $this->db->query("Delete from tv_cast where tv_id = '{$tvid}'");
    while($i < $count){
        $this->db->query("Insert into tv_cast (tv_id, artist_id,artist_as)
                Values ('{$tvid}','{$post['tv_cast_as_artist_id'][$i]}','{$post['tv_cast_as_artist_as'][$i]}'
        )");
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Error I am getting:

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`s Ex-Boyfriend' )`' at line 2
>
> `Insert into tv_cast (tv_id, artist_id,artist_as) Values ('29','7174','Rashmi's Ex-Boyfriend' )`
>
> Filename: /home/divazmed/public_html/design/models/admin_model.php
>
> Line Number: 612

Comment: The error description is VERY self-explaining. Use [variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) [binding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to avoid traps like this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `artist_as` field has not been escaped properly.

Use something like:

```
$data = array(
   'tv_id' => $tvid ,
   'artist_id' => $post['tv_cast_as_artist_id'][$i] ,
   'artist_as' => $post['tv_cast_as_artist_as'][$i]
);

$this -> db -> insert('tv_cast', $data);
```

All of your values will be auto-escaped producing safer queries, etc

You can read more about the Codeigniter Active Record class here:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert

Answer (score 0):

For adding data in mysql:
`html_entities(mysql_real_escape_string($variable));`

For print on page you can use:
`html_entity_decode(stripslashes($variable));`